# ReactJS+browserify+babel: unknown token error

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, browserify, babeljs

I use:

```
"react": "^0.14.2"
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.2",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
"babelify": "^7.2.0",
"browser-sync": "^2.10.0",
"browserify": "^12.0.1",
"browserify-shim": "^3.8.11",
```

This is my gulpfile configuration:

```
// Compile and Watch
function compile() {

var bundler = watchify(browserify(
    {
        entries: source.jsx,
        debug: true,
        extensions: ['.jsx'],
        plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
    }).transform(babel, {presets: ['es2015','stage-0', 'react']}));

function rebundle() {
    bundler.bundle()
        .on('error', function(err) {console.error(err); this.emit('end'); })
        .pipe(vinyl_source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe($.if(useSourceMaps, $.sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true })))
        .pipe($.if(useSourceMaps, $.sourcemaps.write('./')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist.scripts));
}

if (watch) {
    // watch html

    gulp.watch(source.html, ['replaceHTML']);

    bundler.on('update', function() {
        console.log('-> rebundle...');
        rebundle();
    })
}

    rebundle();
}

function watch() {
    return compile(true);
}


// build jsx
gulp.task('build', function() {
    return compile();
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    return watch();
});
```

My .babelrc file in the main directory has following content:

```
{ "presets": ["es2015","stage-0","react"] }
```

This is what I am trying to run ([source](https://gist.github.com/andyl/b3e5ca4d87ad6ad1728d)):

```
R = React.DOM

nations = ['britain', 'ireland', 'norway', 'sweden', 'denmark', 'germany',
  'holland', 'belgium', 'france', 'spain', 'portugal', 'italy',     'switzerland']

Typeahead = React.createClass
  getInitialState : -> {input: ""}
  handleChange    : -> @setState input: @refs.field.getDOMNode().value
  handleClick     : (nation)-> @setState input: nation
  matches         : (input)->
  regex = new RegExp(input, "i")
_.select nations, (nation)-> nation.match(regex) && nation != input
  render: ->
    R.div {},
      R.input {ref:'field', onChange: @handleChange, value: @state.input}
      R.br {}
      _.map @matches(@state.input), (nation)=>
        Button {handleClick: @handleClick, name: nation}

Button = React.createClass
  onClick: -> @props.handleClick(@props.name)
  render:  ->
    classes = "btn btn-xs btn-default"
    R.button {className: classes, onClick: @onClick}, @props.name

$(document).ready ->
  React.render React.createFactory(Typeahead)(), $('#typetest')[0]
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
 Unexpected token (16:21) while parsing file: ...
```

Which is the following line:

```
getInitialState : -> {input: ""}
```

And most probably caused by the "->" sign. Why is this happening even with all the setup in gulp?

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: It is Javascript.

Comment: It's definitely not JavaScript which is why you’re getting the “Unexpected token” error. It looks like CoffeeScript but I’m not that familiar with it. Babel is more focussed on future ECMAScript versions so pairing it with CoffeeScript might be odd. Perhaps you can convert it before using Babel?